# Voting to delete on consecutive duplicates asked from the same user

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

Normally, duplicate questions are not deleted. The idea is that the duplicate helps finding the duplicated question.

Should duplicates asked from the same user in short time be voted to be deleted? (I am thinking of a period of time that is maximum an hour.) Does that depend from the text used for the question?
Should questions asked from a user who keeps creating a new question instead of editing the original one be voted to deletion too? Is this valid even if the questions are created every 8 hours?

Comment: I've been voting to Close, but also flagging these, choosing Other and explaining. All the ones I've seen, the user is saying in the question "I know I have asked this before and I'm going to keep asking it as long as you morons keep closing it" - I figure a mod probably can do a little educating and or cleaning up at that point

Comment: It could also mean the user doesn't understand how Stack Exchange sites work, and that he can edit his own questions. None less, those repeated questions are noise.